# How can I write (xyz) coordinates in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols, coordinates

After looking online, I can't seem to find a command to replicate coordinate notation as shown in the image below.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Example]

Comment: Look up `pmatrix`. Or, alternately, `\parenVectorstack`.

Comment: Thank you @StevenB.Segletes, pmatrix works well.

Comment: To be honest, I'd avoid so heavy notation inline. Why not just making the convention that `(x,y,z)` is just an alternative notation for `\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}`? Or use `(x\ y\ z)^T` when inline.